# How to avoid the duplicate value while joing two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I am preparing a questionnaire in **code-igniter** frame work.At a time one question is displayed for answering.The answered questions are entered into a temporary table.If the page is refreshed already answered questions are again displayed.For that I tried to join the temporary table and main table but its not working.I used the following query,

```
"SELECT a.boxes FROM quest a LEFT JOIN useranswer1 b ON  a.boxes!=b.question"
```

quest is main table and useranswer1 is temporary table.

The result contain all the values in the main table(`quest`). I need the values which are not in the `useranswer1`(temporary table). Is it possible using join query or any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.boxes 
FROM quest a 
LEFT JOIN useranswer1 b ON  a.boxes = b.question
WHERE b.question IS NULL;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT a.boxes 
FROM quest a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM useranswer1 b 
                  WHERE a.boxes = b.question);
```

Comment: Hi,I tried this query and its working.Along with the above query i want to check an id limit.I tried as"select a.boxes from quest a where NOT EXISTS(select 1 from useranswer1 b where a.boxes=b.question) and eid=$id limit $offset,$page" .In this 'eid' is a field in table 'quest'.Some time this query return empty result set.please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery with NOT IN clause like:

```
SELECT boxes 
FROM quest
WHERE boxes NOT IN 
              (SELECT DISTINCT question
               FROM useranswer1)
```